# Is there a more efficient way to run this on page load and resize?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this to dynamically adjust the body top margin when the window is resized, for responsiveness.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').css('margin-top', $('#header').height());
});
```

But I'm trying to find a more efficient way to run the same line on page load, without just coping the line again like:

```
$('body').css('margin-top', $('#header').height());
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('body').css('margin-top', $('#header').height());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, it is best practice to run the code inside resizing events within a timeout. Also, it is a good idea to save the elements in a variable.

Last but not least, use namespaces for your events to trigger them explicitly.

```
var winresizeT,
    $body = $('body'),
    $window = $(window),
    $header = $('#header');

$window.on('resize.bodymargin', function() {
  clearTimeout(winresizeT);
  winresizeT = setTimeout(function() {
    $body.css('margin-top', $header.height() + 'px');
  }, 30);
});

$window.on('load', function() {
  $window.trigger('resize.bodymargin');
});
```

Comment: when you resize the window, the function is called for every pixel you change the window size, which is very performance-hungry. if you just do the changes once the window *has been* resized, it is much more fluid and you wont even see the difference

Comment: @Lee the timeout means "only run this code if the window hasnt been resized for the last 30 milliseconds. you can play with that value :)

Comment: @Lee you also might want to add `px`, since `.height()` only returns an integer